# Simplifying a ratio

Tags: factoring, ratio

I don't remember how to simplify a ratio from this answer:

> **Step 2:** Calculate the required ratio
>   \begin{align}
> & \text{Population of city $C$ above poverty line: population of city $G$ above poverty line} \\
> =& 0.0966Y:0.0462Y \\
> =& {\bf 23:11}
> \end{align}

I got $0.0966Y:0.0462Y$, but I'm not sure what is the equation to simplify that to  $\bf 23:11$.

Comment: Please [do not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{cancel}\dfrac{0.0966Y}{0.0462Y}=\dfrac{966\times\cancel{0.0001}\times\cancel{Y}}{462\times\cancel{0.0001}\times\cancel{Y}}=\dfrac{966}{462}=\dfrac{\cancel{42}\times 23}{\cancel{42}\times 11}=\dfrac{23}{11}$

Comment: thanks. so we need to find the biggest number they can both be divided by? is there a trick to find that quickly?

Comment: it is called the gcd https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor.